# Passing AWS Credentials in Python Script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ses

I have a python script that gets called by a PHP. The user that invokes this php script is `apache` and hence, the python file also gets invoked by `apache`. So, it gives "Unable to locate credentials ". I've set the default credentials via awscli and when I invoke the python script as root, it works.

This is my line of code :

```
client = boto3.client('ses', region_name=awsregion, aws_access_key_id='AJHHJHJHJ', aws_secret_access_key='asdasd/asdasd/asd')
```

But, this gives "Invalid Syntax" Error. So, I tried this :

```
client = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id='ASDASD', aws_secret_access_key='asd/asdasd/asdasd')
client = boto3.client('ses', region_name=awsregion, aws_access_key_id='ASDASD', aws_secret_access_key='asd/asdasd/asdasd')
```

Gives the same error as above. Weird thing is that this same thing is [mentioned in the documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#method-parameters). Even though it's not recommended, it should work.

Can somebody help me in fixing this?

Comment: Could you show the actual traceback you are getting?  The first call you show to create the client looks ok to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you ever get this resolved? Here is how I connect to boto3 in my Python scripts:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import re
from io import BytesIO
import gzip
import datetime
import dateutil.parser as dparser
from datetime import datetime
import tarfile
import requests
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## Needed glue stuff
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)

## 
## currently this will run for everything that is in the staging directory     of omniture

# set needed parms
myProfileName = 'MyDataLake'
dhiBucket = 'data-lake'
#create boto3 session
try:    
    session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id='aaaaaaaaaaaa',     aws_secret_access_key='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', region_name='us-east-1')aws_session_token=None, region_name=None, botocore_session=None
    s3 = session.resource('s3') #establish connection to s3
except Exception as conne:
    print ("Unable to connect:  " + str(conne))
    errtxt = requests.post("https://errorcapturesite", data={'message':'Unable to connect to : ' + myProfileName, 'notify':True,'color':'red'})
    print(errtxt.text) 
    exit()
```